# Java cannot find symbol symbol : method getFiles()

Tags: java, imagej, filedialog

I'm trying to use java.awt.FileDialog in an ImageJ plugin but for some reason I am getting an error that Java cannot find the getFiles method:

> C:\File_Opener3.java:50: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   getFiles() location: class java.awt.FileDialog        fd.getFiles();
>           ^ 1 error

I get a similar error when trying setMultipleMode, but other methods like setVisible and getFile work fine. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import ij.plugin.*;
import ij.*;
import ij.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;

import ij.gui.*;
import ij.plugin.frame.Recorder;
import ij.util.Java2;
import ij.macro.Interpreter;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;

// Try to figure out why this only allows list veiw
public class File_Opener3  implements PlugIn {
    //static File dir;

    private static Frame sharedFrame;
    private String dir;
        private String name;

    public void run(String arg) {
        openFiles();
        IJ.register( File_Opener .class);
    }

    public void openFiles() {
        Frame parent = IJ.getInstance();
        if (parent==null) {
            if (sharedFrame==null) sharedFrame = new Frame();
                parent = sharedFrame;
            }
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(parent, "title"); // From Java.awt.FileDialog
        fd.setVisible(true);
        //fd.setMultipleMode(true);
        name = fd.getFile();
            if (name==null) {
                if (IJ.isMacOSX())
                    System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "false");
                Macro.abort();
            } else
                dir = fd.getDirectory();


        //File[] files = fd.getFiles();
        fd.getFiles();
        //IJ.log("48 fd.getFilenameFilter(): "+fd.getFilenameFilter());
        Opener opener = new Opener();
        //opener.openMultiple();
/*      for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            ImagePlus img = opener.openImage(path, files[i].getName());
            if (img!=null)
                img.show();
        }    */    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FileDialog.getFiles()` and `FileDialog.setMultipleMode()` were introduced in Java 1.7. You are probably compiling against an earlier version of Java. If you're using an IDE, check the source level that's set for your project.

Comment: Unfortunately you are correct, my "About ImageJ" says Java 1.6.0 even though I have 1.8 installed.

Comment: @user1639187 - Perhaps [this FAQ](http://fiji.sc/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_launch_ImageJ_with_a_different_version_of_Java.3F) will help. (Or perhaps not. I don't know anything about ImageJ.)

Comment: Thanks Ted, i was just trying that and now have "class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0" when I compile.

Comment: @user1639187 Unfortunately, ImageJ's Script Editor does not work with Java 7+. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/fiji/fiji/issues/119) which we plan to resolve before summer's end. But the Script Editor also has other [critical bugs](https://github.com/scijava/scripting-java/issues/5) relating to Java plugin development. I suggest using an IDE to develop your plugins; in particular, I heartily recommend Eclipse. See [this guide](http://imagej.net/Developing_ImageJ_in_Eclipse) and use the [minimal-ij1-plugin](https://github.com/imagej/minimal-ij1-plugin) project as a starting point.